# Error when deleting a file after Xdocument Load

Tags: c#, xml, csv

So.... Basically I need to create a little program that will convert XML data to CSV. I have everything done...almost

All of the code runs great, there is only one problem. As soon as everything is done, I want the xml file to be deleted. Although it won't really let me throwing me an error on the Xdocument.Load line.

As soon as the file gets deleted, the Xdocument.Load is telling me that it can't find the file, but everything is done, I don't need it to try to load the file that has been deleted...

Here's most of my code :

```
        static void Main()
    {
        
        using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\XML");

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.Security
                             | NotifyFilters.Size;

        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        watcher.Error += OnError;

        watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


            private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
        {
            return;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        string delimiter = ",";
        string path = $"{e.FullPath}";
        XDocument loadInvoices = XDocument.Load(path);
        string invoiceText = loadInvoices.ToString();
        var invoice = XElement.Parse(invoiceText);
        string supplierName = "";
        string invoicePO = "";


        sb.Append("Supplier" + delimiter);

        foreach (var item in invoice.Descendants("Fields").Descendants("Field").ToList())
        {
            sb.Append(item.Attribute("Name").Value.Replace("é","e")+ delimiter);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        foreach (var item in invoice.Descendants("Supplier").ToList())
        {
            supplierName = item.Element("Name").Value;
            sb.Append(supplierName + delimiter);
        }
        foreach (var item in invoice.Descendants("Fields").Descendants("Field").ToList())
        {
            string temp = item.Attribute("Type").Value;
            if (temp != "invoiceordernumber")
            {               
                sb.Append(item.Value + delimiter);
            }
            else
            {
                invoicePO = item.Value;
                sb.Append(item.Value + delimiter);
            }
            
        }

        
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\XML\"+ supplierName +"_PO#"+ invoicePO + ".csv");
         sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
        loadInvoices = null;
        File.Delete(path);

        
    }

    private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File " + e.FullPath + " started copying : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fileStream = File.Open(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                Console.WriteLine("File is copied : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                fileStream.Close();
                
                //there is the point when the file is completed copying .... now you should be able to access the file and process it.
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException ioException) { }


        }
    }

    private static void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted: {e.FullPath}");

    private static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed:");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Old: {e.OldFullPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    New: {e.FullPath}");
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
        PrintException(e.GetException());

    private static void PrintException(Exception? ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine();
            PrintException(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: If you don't want `XDocument.Load` to load... then don't call it. From your description it sounds as though you're calling this in a loop or based on some other triggered condition that isn't cleared just because you deleted the file. Your code as written will not produce this error on its own.

Comment: Try by setting `loadInvoices = null;`

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't need to load the document for it to be processed?

Comment: Not after it's been *deleted*, no. You are deleting the file *after* loading it. The only way `XDocument.Load` could give an exception is if you're calling it *again*, after deleting the file.

Comment: @McNets Just tried, didn't work :(

Comment: @JeroenMostert I use FileSystemWatcher to create a type of "hot folder". On change I need it to read the xml, append and create a csv file and then delete. Is it because even if I have OnChanged and OnDelete, it's taken as a OnChanged and tries to go at it again?

Comment: That sounds like a very likely cause, yes. This is why we encourage people to produce a [mre] with enough code to show the problem. :P Either remove the `OnDelete` trigger or check in the event what the type of the notification is -- obviously you don't want to respond to a delete with a file load.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's updated, if you don't mind taking a look

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem caused by running this code in a loop or some other way that causes it to be re-run after it has been completed.

I recommend you try to debug and see what is happening there and why it's re-run.

Other than that, it's a good idea to check if the file exists before loading it:

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
    return;
XDocument loadInvoices = XDocument.Load(path);
```

This will check if the file exists, if it doesn't then it will exit whatever function your code is in, otherwise, it will continue.

This will probably solve your problem here as it will prevent the code from opening deleted file.

Comment: I use FileSystemWatcher to create a type of "hot folder". On change I need it to read the xml, append and create a csv file and then delete. Is it because even if I have OnChanged and OnDelete, it's taken as a OnChanged and tries to go at it again?

Comment: Is there a chance that the FileSystemWatcher event is triggered a second time when the file is deleted?

Comment: I updated the code in my question. It should not be triggered on delete unless when deleted it starts onChanged

Comment: So... that'S what I did and it worked

string path = $"{e.FullPath}";
if (!File.Exists(path)) { return; }
 XDocument loadInvoices = XDocument.Load(path);

Answer (score 0):

The `FileWatcher` will fire a change event when you delete the file, so it's re-calling your `OnChanged` event handler after the file is gone. This is why your load operation fails.

You can put an `if File.Exists(path)` in there when you attempt to load your XML as the one of the comments recommended, or, after deletion, remove the `OnChanged` event delegate from the `FileWatcher`.